# Does anyone have any examples of grouped pins expanding in crowded areas?

Tags: here-api

I am in the process of implementing a web based JS here.com app that will require overlapping pushpins (many in exactly the same spot). Is there any sort of plugin or example of how to solve the problem similar to this plugin for Google Maps https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

I have searched long and hard but am unable to find anywhere to start tackling this problem.

I just need some way of uncluttering the overlapping markers to allow touch events on all markers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any ready-made solution but you could probably start out with [clustering module](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/clustering/marker-clustering) and take it from there. Write a [custom theme](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/clustering/custom-cluster-theme) that would allow for clusters to expand on click (like arrange them in a grid or something).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/ordering-overlapping-markers on how you can achieve having multiple markers on almost the same point.

> ```js
> function orderMarkers() {
>   var zIndex = 1,
>       // create a set of markers
>       marker = new mapsjs.map.Marker(
>         {lat: 52.508249, lng: 13.338931}
>       ),
>       marker2 = new mapsjs.map.Marker(
>         {lat: 52.506682, lng: 13.332107}
>       ),
>       marker3 = new mapsjs.map.Marker(
>         {lat: 52.503730, lng: 13.331678}
>       ),
>       marker4 = new mapsjs.map.Marker(
>         {lat: 52.531, lng: 13.380}
>       );
>
>   // add markers to the map
>   map.addObjects([marker, marker2, marker3, marker4]);
>
>   map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
>     if (evt.target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
>       // increase z-index of the marker that was tapped
>       evt.target.setZIndex(zIndex++);
>     }
>  });
> }
> ```

Comment: My apologies, the answer was a misclick. I appreciate the help but I am looking for more of a solution to elegantly handle seeing multiple markers in *exactly* the same location at a glance, multiple markers in close proximity would be nice but can be handled by zooming.